# Can anyone help identify the country, rank, and unit this WWI uniform is from?

Tags: world-war-one, identification

[image]

I am looking to ID country, rank, and unit shown in this picture.

I have already tried googling the collar insignia with no luck.

Comment: Some info on the photo studio: https://www.gri.it/fotografi-in-italia-1839-1939/toscana/firenze/180-alvino-c-firenze.html

Comment: @AllInOne I'm curious: how do you know this is the studio?

Comment: @kimchilover in lower right is studio mark. “R Alvino. Firenze”. Linked article seems to say they closed in 1915.

Comment: The collar patch appears to be cavalry

Comment: Wow!  Good noticing.

Comment: The uniform looks British to me.  The collar patches might also be Royal Engineers.   I see a circled A with a bunch of flames coming out from the top.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely an officers uniform of the 1st French foreign legion regiment due to the collar patch with a "1" in the hollowed out grenade though I believe he is wearing the British style "new tunic" which was introduced in spring 1915 for Officers though this was unpopular in the Army except for its Aviation Branch.

Example of the collar patch from
"[The French army in the first world war uniforms and equipment volume 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019NEPX6O) - Laurent Mirouze"

[image: Collar tabs showing a "1" inside a hollow grenade]